# How to detect overflow while arithmetic in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am working on a analysis problem in python in which I have to work on big `floating` point numbers and was performing some operations on it. My codes seems to break in between; looking carefully I found that sometimes a simple add operation would return `inf` it must be an overflow.

```
>>> a = float(2**1022) + float(2**1023)
>>> print a
1.348269851146737e+308
>>> a = float(2**1023) + float(2**1023)
>>> print a
inf
>>>
```

How do we check for `overflow` in python while floating point operation since instead of giving a `OverflowError` it silently gives a value `inf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only imagine checking `if abs(a)==float('inf'): raise OverflowError()`…

Answer (score 3):

Use an arbitrary precision library like GMPY and you won't need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

The [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library supports both arbitrary precision (to decrease the occurrences of overflow) and the ability to trap on floating point events. Here is an example of modify the context to automatically raise an exception when an overflow occurs.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> from gmpy2 import get_context,set_context, ieee, mpfr
>>> set_context(ieee(64))
>>> get_context()
context(precision=53, real_prec=Default, imag_prec=Default,
        round=RoundToNearest, real_round=Default, imag_round=Default,
        emax=1024, emin=-1073,
        subnormalize=True,
        trap_underflow=False, underflow=False,
        trap_overflow=False, overflow=False,
        trap_inexact=False, inexact=False,
        trap_invalid=False, invalid=False,
        trap_erange=False, erange=False,
        trap_divzero=False, divzero=False,
        trap_expbound=False,
        allow_complex=False)
>>> get_context().trap_overflow=True
>>> get_context()
context(precision=53, real_prec=Default, imag_prec=Default,
        round=RoundToNearest, real_round=Default, imag_round=Default,
        emax=1024, emin=-1073,
        subnormalize=True,
        trap_underflow=False, underflow=False,
        trap_overflow=True, overflow=False,
        trap_inexact=False, inexact=False,
        trap_invalid=False, invalid=False,
        trap_erange=False, erange=False,
        trap_divzero=False, divzero=False,
        trap_expbound=False,
        allow_complex=False)
>>> mpfr(2**1023) + mpfr(2**1023)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
gmpy2.OverflowResultError: 'mpfr' overflow in "addition"
>>>
```